# Tier Pricing Issue

Tags: magento-1.6

Does Magento take Tier pricing into account in layered navigation? I am not able to filter products properly with tier pricing. That means price range selection is not working in layered navigation. I have searched a lot but am not able to get to the exact problem.

In the printed query itself is not having any condition for tier price, its having condition for `price_index.min_price`

Comment: Afaik the tier price is used when the price index is built. So yes, it should be used.

Comment: Thanks @FabianBlechschmidt, I reindexed all data however it does not seems to be working.

Comment: I have checked. min_price is not getting set for simple products

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue yet?

Comment: @ArjenMiedema, it has been a long time and i forgot the solution, will post once I get that